# ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './uploads/65d87d8ebc4222fbdb044070' in Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, vercel

The below code works fine in localhost, but on Vercel, it gives the following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir './uploads/65d87d8ebc4222fbdb044070'
```

Code for creating a folder and adding a file in it if it does not exist:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    const { userId } = req.user;
    const dir = `./uploads/${userId}`;
    fs.access(dir, fs.constants.F_OK, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return fs.mkdir(dir, (error) => cb(error, dir));
      }
      return cb(null, dir);
    });
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    const newFileName = `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`;
    cb(null, newFileName);
  },
});
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?